# Condition based on environment in Ant buildfile

Tags: ant

I am new to Ant and any help will be appreciated.

What I want to do is:

```
<target name="run-tenantManagement" depends="jar"
        description="Running TestNG Tests">
    <if> ... SIMV3.1 env variable set 
     <property name="output.dir.name" value="tenantManagementV3"/>
    <else>
     <property name="output.dir.name" value="tenantManagement"/>
    </if>
</target>
```

Basically I am setting one env variable
**setenv SIMV3.1 true**

I want to put a check in the Ant target if this variable is set and has value=true, then set output.dir.name to a particular value, else set it to another value.

Kindly help.  I have googled through many Ant tutorials but everything seems ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this, for example using an Ant [`<condition> task`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html):

```
<property environment="env" />
<condition property="output.dir.name" value="tenantManagementV3"
                                      else="tenantManagement">
    <istrue value="${env.SIMV3.1}" />
</condition>
```

There are a number of other tests you can use and combine in the task, see *[Conditions](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html)* for the list.

Also: I'd avoid using an environment variable name with an embedded dot - it won't work in all shells.